# Why non-optional relationship is optional in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I set relationship be non-optional

[image]

But generated `codegen` class / file contains optional.

[image]

Comment: Because the `Delete Rule` is Nullify. Only way to nullify the relationship is to be optional. Otherwise, choose Cascade/Delete. There's also not really a way to represent that the relationship does NOT exist.

Comment: `Cascade Delete the objects at the destination of the relationship when you delete the source.` I have a to-many relationship here, and I set cascade delete in the **parent** entity not in child.